# Should I disable secure boot to install arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, bios, secure-boot

I have copied arch linux iso image in a usb using rufus. I want to install arch linux on my laptop But should I disable Secure Boot in BIOS settings? Many OS Installations need it to be disabled. Is it also true for installing Arch Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For installing it you will need to disable Secure Boot in the BIOS, but after installation [you can re-enable it if you want](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Secure_Boot).

Answer (score 1):

You should disable the secure boot.

[Booting an install media](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Secure_Boot#Booting_an_install_media)

> **Note**: The official installation image does not support Secure Boot (FS#53864). To successfully boot the installation medium you will need to disable Secure Boot.
>
> Secure Boot support was removed starting with archlinux-2016.06.01-dual.iso. At that time prebootloader was replaced with efitools, even though the later uses unsigned EFI binaries. One might want to remaster the Install ISO in a way described by previous topics of this article. For example, the signed EFI applications PreLoader.efi and HashTool.efi from #PreLoader can be adopted to here. Note that up to this point, the article assumed one can access the ESP of the machine. But when installing a machine that never had an OS before, there is no ESP present. You should explore other articles, for example Unified Extensible Firmware Interface#Create UEFI bootable USB from ISO, to learn how this situation should be handled.